# How to change javascript files according to the screen size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can anybody tell me how to change a JavaScript file according to screen size of an HTML page?
Actually i'm making an adoptive website and I need to change some js files according to the screen size. Actually these js files are for a banner for this site so the banner will be changed when the screen size change. So if guys knows how to make a  code that replace the files in HTML page when user change the screen size or when it displayed on different devices.

If anybody knows please tell me thanks.

Thanks for every member who answered before....

Comment: Why not write the JavaScript to adapt to the screen size?  What if the user changes the screen size (e.g. on an iPhone changes the orientation) while browsing?

Comment: You should use CSS media queries instead.

Comment: Your question sounds odd.. you want to change the size of your JavaScript file?

Comment: can you please explain it, I'm new to it...

Comment: you want to change the actual files themselves? why?

Comment: if anyone understands what it says here i'll remove my downvote

Comment: I just want to replace the javascript files in html head section when the screen size change, one file for low resolution and other for high resolution... Is you know the Media queries for changing the file through css then let me know... thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check out these two links about accessing the screen's width and dynamically loading a script.

[Screen width](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_screen_width.asp)
[Dynamically load js file](http://unixpapa.com/js/dyna.html)

You are going to want to check the value of the screen's width and then based on the width, dynamically load a Javascript file.

```
<script>
if (screen.width > 500) {
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = 'helper.js';
    head.appendChild(script);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply it was really helpful but still facing a prblem... This is the code is altered...<script>
                if (screen.width >= 1250) {
                    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
                    var script = document.createElement('script');
                    script.type = 'text/javascript';
                    script.src = 'edge_includes/index1250_edgePreload.js';
                    head.appendChild(script);
                }

Comment: else  {
                    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
                    var script = document.createElement('script');
                    script.type = 'text/javascript';
                    script.src = 'edge_includes/index_edgePreload.js';
                    head.appendChild(script);
                }
            </script>

But when i change the window size it still folowing to the first file...

Comment: [Look here](http://jsbin.com/eqiqim/2/edit) this is a snippet of code that might help. I am not sure why you need to do this but this is a start and then you can create listeners for more functionality.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$(window).on('resize', function() {...})` and getScript `$.getScript('myScript.js')`.

**BUT BE AWARE, all scripts loaded KEEPS loaded so if the window is resized again you can't remove a script already loaded.**

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply... Actually i'm making an adoptive site and i want to add a javascript animated banner, so banner will be change when the screen size change... so if you know the better way to do this please tell me... I can't write javascript by myself... if this is possible in css media queries..?

Comment: Media queries are the best but it's only available in modern browser.